# Calculating Power Dissipation in a Filter

Tags: power, power-dissipation

Apologies in advance if my question seems too basic. I don't really know where to go from here.

I understand that power can be calculated as *P = IV* or *P = V^2/R* or *P = I^2 x R*. I think I'm not conceptually understanding how to actually use these formulas together to calculate power dissipation in a component.

For instance, I have this filter [here](https://www.murata.com/en-eu/api/pdfdownloadapi?cate=luNoiseSupprFilteBlockType&partno=BNX012-01). Its datasheet has a bunch of useful information, in particular rated voltage and rated current, 50Vdc and 15A respectively. I really don't believe I have the correct value for power dissipation if I just multiply the two values and get 750W. That seems far too much to be believable.

If I want to calculate how much power this filter dissipates, where can I find the correct values to calculate power dissipation in this component?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This microwave DC filter has specs;

Large rated current (15A) and Low Rdc
(0.8m ohm-typ.)

So \$Pd=I^2R= 15^2* 0.0008 \Omega=0.18W\$

The voltage is for the magnet wire insulation breakdown rating (when scored)